# Input type checkbox cant style proprerly

Tags: html, css

I want to style a checkbox I don't have a label though .i but my styling is not applied for that input I couldn't figure out why.be fore I ask this I went through some similar issue in the stack overflow but nothing works for me. I will add my codepen example with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
   </body>
</html>
```

My styling

```
input[type=checkbox]:before {
  background-color: #00f279;
  border-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
     transform: scale(1.5);
     -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
      padding: 5px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-color :#ffffff;
 }
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/chamara_w/pen/oNvRrbE)

Comment: You can't style a checkbox cross browser unfortunately. What you need is the so called [checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). What you'll basically be doing is hiding the current checkbox and making a fake one. Then people will be actually clicking on the label instead of the actual checkbox and your actual checkbox will still work properly. The question is, is it okay to add a label? If so, then you're good to go.

Comment: Let's try to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css). I hope it will be useful for You

Comment: have a look on this example : https://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply  `-webkit-appearance: none;`. This will remove all browser styles and you try applying your style.

```
input[type=checkbox]{
 border:1px solid red;
 transform: scale(1.5);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color :#ffffff;
```

}

Now on the checked state, you have to apply another css with the background image.

Answer (score 0):

add **Height** and **width** as well, for [after || before ] you need to add (**content** too ) in css

checkout this

```
input[type=checkbox]:before {
  content:'x';
  background-color: #00f279;
  border-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
     transform: scale(1.5);
     -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
      padding: 5px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-color :#ffffff;
  height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
 }
```